# how can i avoid multiple joins on the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to know how I can avoid all of these left joins with just 1 left join, or anything else that would require less joins?

```
select colums
  FROM [SectionAUnresolved] a
  left join sectionanotmarkedcounts sdirector
  on a.director=sdirector.employee

  left join sectionanotmarkedcounts s_rm
  on a.rm=s_rm.employee

  left join sectionanotmarkedcounts s_rep
  on a.rep=s_rep.employee

  left join sectionanotmarkedcounts s_css
  on a.css=s_css.employee

  left join sectionanotmarkedcounts s_Css2
  on a.css2=s_Css2.employee
```

thank you for your guidance!

Comment: not possible to answer in its current form.

Comment: What are you trying to acheve with these joins? What do you expect in the result?

Comment: can you give us some more details on table structure, etc. of your database? We can't answer your question in its current form

Comment: Is this what you need: `...left join sectionanotmarkedcounts s on a.director=s.employee and a.rm=s.employee and ...` ?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can change your schema, such that the data you are returning from the left joined tables is contained within SectionAUnresolved. You can do this either by:

1. Directly writing the data to the appropriate columns; or
2. Having empty columns which you update later in batch

There is not much background on your question. So it's difficult to give you an absolute answer to your particular problem. But generally this would be the answer to your question.

You shouldn't be scared of joins, and if performance is an issue, indexes on key fields, and/or the use of views (materialized or not) and/or partition and any number of other performance enhancing tools are recommended.

**Update**

@Konstantin-Vasilcov's idea looked like a good possibility, although slightly incorrect (requiring or, not and)

```
 select colums
  FROM [SectionAUnresolved] a
  left join sectionanotmarkedcounts [all]
  on a.director=[all].employee
    or a.rm=[all].employee
    or a.rep=[all].employee
    or a.css=[all].employee
    or a.css2=[all].employee
```

This would however result in multiplying the records, not a problem if you can subsequently pivot with your application, although this would not provide information about what relationship was used. So a change in your schema, normalizing your SectionAUnresolved table would be needed.

```
 select ct.type, colums
  FROM [SectionAUnresolved] a
  left join SectionAUnresolved_countTypes ct
    on ct.Unresolvedid = a.id
  left join sectionanotmarkedcounts [all]
    on ct.employee=[all].employee
```

Where:

- ct.type {director, rm, rep,css,css2}
- "ct.Unresolvedid = a.id" - links the new SectionAUnresolved_countTypes table to the single SectionAUnresolved rows

Reducing your joins to 2, and allowing more "countTypes" without increasing the number of joins, or any schema changes.

**Update**

Thanks to @Conrad-Flix, you can use a case statement to determine what join was used for each record returned (see my first code snippet above). Doing this would mean you don't have to normalize the SecionAUnresolved table further, however you might still need to do so, depending on performance.

From my knowledge case statements are not indexed, and may require materialized view indexing for optimizing. Normalizing would still be a better structural improvement, IMO.

Comment: *although this would not provide information about what relationship was used.* You could include a series of case statements to determine which ones were used. e.g.  `CASE WHEN a.director=[all].employee THEN 1 ELSE 0 END director,  CASE WHEN a.rm=[all].employee THEN 1 ELSE 0 END rm..`

Comment: added to answer, and note that a better form is: `CASE WHEN Condition1 THEN Value1 WHEN Condition2 THEN Value2 END` more like an Else-If stucture, eliminating the nesting. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for more examples. UPDATE: Just realised you had separate fields, not nested cases. My assumption and favoured approach is to return a Enumerated value to the application layer in a single field.

Comment: I like enumerated values as well but unless there's something ensuring director, rm, rep, css and cc2 are distinct values it would need to be separate fields or a bit field.

Comment: Yeah you're right, if an employee it attributed to multiple joins, then only the first will match.

Answer (score 0):

The short and simple answer is "no".

...because the data you want lives in different rows, you must join to get it. There's no getting around it.